# c struct to Python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have the following c code:

```
rx_data_t* readBuffer()
{
    rx_data_t buffer[512];

    results = doSomething()

    rx_data_t* newBuf = malloc(results.count());

    for(i=0;i<results.count();i++)
    {
        newBuf[i].receive_time = buffer[i].receive_time;
        newBuf[i].low = buffer[i].low;
        newBuf[i].high = buffer[i].high;
    }

    return newBuf;
}
```

I am using ctypes in Python (3.4) to get the results of this function,

```
 class BufferResults(ctypes.Structure):
    """ creates a struct to match rx_data_t
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ('receive_time', ctypes.c_ulong),
        ('low', ctypes.c_ushort),
        ('high', ctypes.c_ushort)
    ]

self.lib.readBuffer.restype = ctypes.POINTER(BufferResults)

res = self.lib.readBuffer()
```

This works and I get all the results from the c structure, however if I iterate through res there are hundreds of results rather than the one or two I'm expecting.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or not doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Not done this myself, so not trying to post an answer but ... is python expecting a *list* of data structures? Do you need to return a length of 1 somewhere in there? Also, where are those `self.lib` calls meant to be? By the indentation they aren't part of the class.

Comment: The indentation looks correct; the class is just to define the `BufferResults` structure.